# Для чего конкретно предназначен http?

Tags: сервер, http, протоколы

Я так понимаю, что http - это протокол, который позволяет осуществлять передачу информации между клиентом и сервером. На данный момент этот протокол используется везде: при открытии нужной веб-страницы, скачивании музыки, видео, приложения...

Но мне не совсем понятно что именно делает http протокол во время передачи информации. Если, как я прочитал, протокол по своей сути - это набор правил, то http всего лишь устанавливает правила для передачи информации между сервером и клиентом? Если это так, то что это за правила и зачем они?

Comment: "зачем они?" --- А зачем правила дорожного движения, например?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  для того, чтобы обеспечить безопасность... правила http также позволяют надежно доставить файл получателю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http предназначен для передачи данных. Он проводник между сервером и клиентом. А правила нужны для передачи (грубо говоря, если пользователь введёт определённый URL-адрес, то будет найдена и отображена информация соответствующая этому адресу). Если вы сталкивались с программированием, то знаете, что программа в которой нет кода (правил) ничего не выполняет - это просто пустой файл.

Тут про HTTP подробнее: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Я сумел ответить на Ваш вопрос?

Comment: а, то есть под правилами подразумевается просто набор действий, который этот протокол будет делать в тех или иных ситуациях. То есть, как я понимаю, если url найден, то http возвращает страницу, если нет - код с ошибкой... Правильно понял?

Comment: Да, всё верно! Вводя URL Вы выполняете поиск в базе данных WWW (World Wide Web). Если находится сайт (файлы сайта), то они загружаются Вам на страницу, а если нет, то сообщается, что страница не найдена (это тоже правило - правило, выполняющееся при исключении).

Comment: И еще один вопрос. Эти правила, как я понимаю, регулируются методами http (get, post...)?

Comment: Эти правила прописали в коде разработчики WWW. Что они указали в кодах мне, к сожалению, не известно.

Answer (score 2):

В определенном смысле, сетевой протокол можно рассматривать как набор бланков для подачи анкет куда-либо.

Вот вы когда бумажное письмо отправляете (хотя кто это делает в 2020...), вы на конверте в нужные поля, аккуратно заполняете. Запоните неверно - письмо дойдет не туда или почтальон его у вас не возьмет.

Вот сетевой протокол - это и есть набор таких бланков на все случаи жизни. Хочет клиент получить страницу - заполняет бланк

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер в ответ также берет и заполняет бланк, только уже другой - бланк ответа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так оно себе и работает.